# Binding click and onchange events together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function that fires on every `change` event, meaning everytime a `radio` button is selected from a `select` list, an empty array updates and displays the content in two different `HTML` elements: one is `div` and the other is `ul`. In the `div`, I would like to display additional `radio` button that, if clicked, should also deselect the selected `radio` buttons from the main list and the `ul`.

Heres the HTML:

```
<select id="selectionContainer">
    <option value="Brown">Brown</option>
    <option value="Nicole">Nicole</option>
    <option value="Jack">Jack</option>
</select>

<div id="selectedOptions">
// Selected items from `someOptions` will be displayed here as divs with classes
</div>
<div id="selectedOptionsList">
// Selected items from `someOptions` will be displayed here as list items
</div>
```

Heres the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selectionContainer').multiselect({
    onChange: function(element, checked) {

        var arr =[];
        var selectionDiv = $('#selectedOptions').empty();

        $('#selectionContainer').find("option:selected").each(function(){
            arr.push($(this).html());
        });


        for(var i in arr) {
            var selectedOption = '<div>' + arr[i] + '<input type="radio" value="' + arr[i] + '" /></div>');
            var optionForList ="<option  value='"+ arr[i] + "'>" + arr[i] + "</option>";
            $(selectionDiv).append(selectedOption);
            $('#selectedOptionsList').append(optionForList);
    }
    });
```

Now, everything seems to work fine and if I select / deselect the options from `someOptions`, the new selection gets updated in the `div` and the `ul`. But how do I bind the newly created `radio` buttons to the change event, so when clicked, they can also deselect the items from the `ul` and `select` elements also?

I was thinking of using the `value` property, I just don't know how to bind the `radio` buttons from `#selectedOptions` to the `on change` event of `#selectionContainer`.

Comment: I don't see `selectionList` defined anywhere, did you mean `selectionDiv` ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `selectedOptionsList`

Comment: @BirdMars Can you [edit] your question? Some other Bird tried to edit it in already, but I believe you are the more correct person to edit it, so it is available in the question

Comment: Can you double check and edit your question with the right ids/variable names please?  For example, `'#selectionContainer'` doesn't exist in your html either, using `$(selectedOptionsList)` might work but `$('#selectedOptionsList')` would be more correct and obvious.

Comment: @James Updated the question with the right names. Thanks for assisting!

Comment: So, your `select` box is multiselect, your radio buttons are however single select (otherwise they would be checkboxes) and the div selectedOptionsList contains options, similar to your `select` box. In the end the `selectionContainer` is the master of the data and the 2 visualisations are just displaying the actively selected ones?

Comment: @Icepickle Exactly, `selectionContainer` is the master of data. The only difference between the two visualisations is that in `selectionDiv` I have additional radio buttons next to displayed options. If clicked, they should deselect all selected `radio` buttons, including the master data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's a problem in this line:

```
  var selectionDiv = $('#selectedOptions').empty();
```

In this case selectionDiv is undefined. I would rather do:

```
$('#selectedOptions').empty();
```

And then, instead of creating string variables you can create DOM objects and bind the events you need. Something like this may work for you:

```
for(var i in arr) {
        var selectedOption = document.createElement('input');
        selectedOption.type="radio";
        selectedOption.value = arr[i];
        selectedOption.addEventListener("change", myfunc);
        var containerDiv = document.createElement('div');
        $(containerDiv).append(selectedOption);

        $('#selectedOptions').append(containerDiv);
        $('#selectedOptionsList').append(optionForList);
}
function myFunc(){
 //Whatever you need to do
}
```